# Return from query that refers tables in two different db

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a goal where I need to write a query in JDBC postprocessor of JMeter but the tables used in query are in different databases. Some tables are in Db2 and others are in PostgreSQL.

I can connect and get response from two databases *i.e.* Db2 and PostgreSQL separately. However when I write query, that refer to tables in different db, I see `relationship doesn't exist error`.

I understand, I can use bound pool variables in JMeter for different db connections.

My question:

1. How can I use these bound pool variables, which are referring to different db (Db2 and PostgreSQL) connection in JMeter, in a single query, if that is possible. Maybe an example will help here, please?
2. If what I mention in 1 is not possible in JMeter, then how can I achieve above mentioned overall goal through JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible either "through jmeter" or "through" any other database client.

If you need to execute 2 separate queries at the same time - you can add 2 [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) elements for 2 databases, 2 [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) samplers and a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer/).

Comment: I need to execute single query with tables in different DBs